# Broken output of man

Tags: man

Apparently `man` started to display some text in a weird way. A guess it is somehow related to escape sequences that are not rendered as expected.

What should I check? I am using MacOS / iterm2 / ohmyzsh.

For instance, `man ls` output is the following:

```
N^HNA^HAM^HME^HE
     l^Hls^Hs -- list directory contents

S^HSY^HYN^HNO^HOP^HPS^HSI^HIS^HS
     l^Hls^Hs [-^H-A^HAB^HBC^HCF^HFG^HGH^HHL^HLO^HOP^HPR^HRS^HST^HTU^HUW^HW@^H@                                                        a^Hab^Hbc^Hcd^Hde^Hef^Hfg^Hgh^Hhi^Hik^Hkl^Hlm^Hmn^Hno^Hop^Hpq^Hqr^Hrs^Hst^Htu^Huw^Hwx^Hx1^H1%^H%] [_^Hf_^Hi_^Hl_^He _^H._^H.      _^H.]

D^HDE^HES^HSC^HCR^HRI^HIP^HPT^HTI^HIO^HON^HN
     For each operand that names a _^Hf_^Hi_^Hl_^He of a type other than directory, l^Hls^Hs displays its name as well as any
     requested, associated information.  For each operand that names a _^Hf_^Hi_^Hl_^He of type directory, l^Hls^Hs displays the       names
     of files contained within that directory, as well as any requested, associated information.
...
```

Comment: This looks less like man is weird, but your terminal is behaving weirdly. I would guess the escapes are interpreted in a weird way leading to this result.

Comment: Have you maybe set the variables `PAGER` or `MANPAGER` to something?

Comment: I was wrong! There is another problem. Whatever is on the receiving end of man doesn't filter reverse line feeds from the input. Example ``man ls > ls.txt`` will generate the same text, ``man ls | col -b > ls-col.txt`` will generate the correct text.

Comment: What is the value of `$TERM`?

Comment: So the ^H are backspaces, what `man` would use on a printer to generate **bold** characters. The most likely cause is a wrong `TERM` setting, so `man` gets confused it formats it for a printer. For `iterm` (don't know about `iterm2`), my `TERM` is `xterm-256color`.

Comment: Thank you guys, it was `MANPAGER` set to `nvimpager`. After I changed it to `less` things got fixed. Not sure what happened to neovim, but that seems to be a separate issue anyway.